# Generic property type to dynamically assign type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am expecting JSON object from an API which is like:

```
{
   "header":{
      "message_type":"message_type",
      "notification_type":"notification_type"
   },
   "body":{
      "id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "related_entity_type":"inbound_funds",
   }
}
```

The problem is that body can have any number and type of props. And, I have corresponding C# Models for each and every Body type. Is there any efficient way to parse and Deserialize these objects to relevant C# Models, dynamically?

I tried this, bus then Body doesn't desterilize at runtime.

```
public class PushNotification : Body
{
    [JsonProperty("header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
}
```

Comment: asked bazillion times ... use dictionary

Comment: or ... maybe you can use generics ... `Response<T> { Header Header; T Body; }` but it dependeds if you know body type at compile time ... but i doubt *"notification_type":"notification_type"*

Comment: I am able to extract the type prior to deserialization but I cannot know at compile time.

Comment: "I am able to extract the type prior to deserialization" show the code you have tried so far. Your question is absolutely unclear. For example how you can define the type

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate approach, you can use JObject from Newtonsoft.Json to parse dynamic json. It can be read from JObject using key value pair

```
JObject jsonString= JObject.Parse(inputJson);
var id=jsonString["body"]["id"];
```

Comment: I am currently handling in similar way, however, there can dozens of variants of Body object. 

are there any best practices to handle this in more generic way?

I tried using Body class as base and then creating other specific prop containing classes. And then used factory pattern to get the correct implementation. But problems again rises because I cannot Deserialize polymorphic child, using parent class object.


Is there any to using factory pattern with Generic types?

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes) can help?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who took time to help me resolve this. Jegan Maria, Selvin and, Jochem!!

I managed to resolve it using dynamic type and factory!

Here are the code samples

API Layer:

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

            var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content)!;

            var message_Type = data.SelectToken("header.message_type")!.Value<string>()!;

            _factory.Type = message_Type;
            var notification = _factory.CreateNotificationType();

            var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content)!;
           
            notification = dynamicObject.ToObject(notification.GetType());

            

            return Ok(notification);
```

Here is the Factory Method:

```
public class PushNotificationFactory : IPushNotificationFactory
```

{
public string Type { get; set; }

```
public dynamic CreateNotificationType()
{        
    var type = Type switch
    {
        "cash_manager_transaction" => new PushNotification<CashManagerTransaction>(),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
    };

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetType());
}
```

}